# excel 2003 database fields - is it possible to change the name

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I am using excel 2003 query to pull information from databases and fields, I would like to rename the field headers but every time I refresh the data it defaults back to the original example

the field name is **stit_ref** which I want to change to **req reference**; if I do a refresh it just goes back to **stit_ref** after editing the cell/refreshing.

Is there a way to keep the edited field names. I attempted to do it via Microsoft Query by editing the Column heading but I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Query you can write custom query and use aliases for selected fields:

```
SELECT stit_ref AS [req reference] FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

In the query definition it should say something like:

SELECT -other fields go here-,**stit_ref** FROM TableName

change that to:

SELECT -other fields go here-,**stit_ref As [req referenc]** FROM TableName